# Tuple or list when using 'in' in an 'if' clause?

Tags: python, list, optimization, tuples, python-internals

Which approach is better? Using a tuple, like:

```
if number in (1, 2):
```

or a list, like:

```
if number in [1, 2]:
```

Which one is recommended for such uses and why (both logical and performance wise)?

Comment: Third option: `set` (which has a faster membership test).

Comment: CPython will do some internal optimisation and store your list literal as a tuple anyway...

Comment: Fourth option: `frozenset`, which has same membership test cost as set, `O(1)`, but because it's immutable, the python interpreter knows the exact size of the hash table it needs to allocate, rather than leaving room for additional elements.

Comment: @IceArdor: but only in Python 3; using a set literal or `frozenset([...])` expression in Python 2 means the object has to be created first, an operation more costly than the membership test against a tuple of equal length.

Comment: List will beat set if the search element is at the first position.

Comment: @sapam: in which case a simple equality test will beat both. You need to take the *average cost* into account here, not the best-case scenario. For 2 elements or more, the set wins. Provided it is a constant stored with the bytecode.

Comment: I totally agree with you. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The CPython interpreter *replaces the second form with the first*.

That's because loading the tuple from a constant is one operation, but the list would be 3 operations; load the two integer contents and build a new list object.

Because you are using a list literal that isn't otherwise reachable, it is substituted for a tuple:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('number in [1, 2]', '<stdin>', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (number)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ((1, 2))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here the second bytecode loads a `(1, 2)` tuple as a constant, in *one* step. Compare this to creating a list object not used in a membership test:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('[1, 2]', '<stdin>', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BUILD_LIST               2
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here N+1 steps are required for a list object of length N.

This substitution is a CPython-specific peephole optimisation; see the [`Python/peephole.c` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/66d6fa61ac38/Python/peephole.c#l84). For **other** Python implementations then, you want to stick with immutable objects instead.

That said, the *best* option when using Python 3.2 and up, is to use a *set literal*:

```
if number in {1, 2}:
```

as the peephole optimiser will replace that with a `frozenset()` object and membership tests against sets are O(1) constant operations:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('number in {1, 2}', '<stdin>', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (number)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (frozenset({1, 2}))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

This optimization was added in [Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations) but wasn't backported to Python 2.

As such, the Python 2 optimiser doesn't recognize this option and the cost of building either a `set` or `frozenset` from the contents is almost guaranteed to be more costly than using a tuple for the test.

Set membership tests are O(1) and fast; testing against a tuple is O(n) worst case. Although testing against a set has to calculate the hash (higher constant cost, cached for immutable types), the cost for testing against a tuple *other than the first element* is always going to be higher. So on average, sets are easily faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('1 in (1, 3, 5)', number=10**7)  # best-case for tuples
0.21154764899984002
>>> timeit.timeit('8 in (1, 3, 5)', number=10**7)  # worst-case for tuples
0.5670104179880582
>>> timeit.timeit('1 in {1, 3, 5}', number=10**7)  # average-case for sets
0.2663505630043801
>>> timeit.timeit('8 in {1, 3, 5}', number=10**7)  # worst-case for sets
0.25939063701662235
```

Comment: I've heard there's some youtube video available by a leading Python expert that explains all the optimisations that (C)Python can do... :p

Comment: @JonClements: *some*, not all. :-P

Comment: In Python 2: `set([1, 2])`

Comment: @IceArdor: No, because the **cost** of building that set is greater than the cost of testing against a tuple. The tuple test is O(N) worst case, while creating the set is guaranteed to cost O(N), plus the membership test. This isn't about literal syntax, this is about the optimizer *recognising* you can replace the set with a `frozenset` constant.

Comment: Many Python programs that really care about efficiency will pre-build the data structure, regexp, etc. that is being matched. So if `ACCEPTABLE = {1,2}` is pre-defined (as a global or phantom kwarg), the only overhead is the testing, not the construction of what's being tested against.

Comment: @JonathanEunice: yes, using a predefined global, function argument default, or class or instance attribute can help there. The OP was asking about using a literal however.

Comment: I don't see any difference in performance on Python 3.6.3: `1 in (1, 3, 5)` -> `32.4 ns ± 0.247`; `8 in (1, 3, 5)` -> `88.1 ns ± 0.194`; `1 in {1, 3, 5}` -> `32.2 ns ± 0.375`; `8 in {1, 3, 5}` -> `89.3 ns ± 0.788`. O(1) vs. O(n) doesn't matter for tiny `n` -- constant factors dominate.

Comment: @jfs: I can't reproduce those numbers on 3.6.4 on OS X. `8 in {1, 3, 5}` is still around 0.26 for 10 million executions, versus 0.51-ish for the `8 in (1, 3, 5)` case.

Comment: @jfs: that said, I am suprised to see your numbers crop up in IPython using `%timeit` and the plain expressions. Putting them into functions produces the timings I expected. See https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/5ac3077c4c36596f976547882ef0bce5

Comment: `ipython %timeit` differs from `python -mperf timeit` for `8 in {1, 3, 5}` case for some reason. It confirms once again that all benchmarks are evil. Conceptually, a tuple is most suitable to represent an immutable sequence.

Comment: @jfs: but this isn't a sequence. It is a set of possible values you are testing against. Containment doesn't care about position in a sequence, only the binary value of 'present' or 'not present'.

Comment: Are set literals still better for `not in` tests?  Since it has to compare to every element?  `timeit` says it's a little worse

Comment: @endolith: Set literals are still better. The timeit test in my answer shows that for the *worst case* they are faster than using a tuple, for the *best case* they are nearly equivalent. That's because sets very much do **not** need to compare every element.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Oh I see, tuple is only faster if the element does exist and it's near the beginning of the tuple

Comment: If the literal is otherwise unreachable and is used in an `in`/`not in` expression, why aren't tuple and list literals similarly automatically replaced with a frozenset?

Comment: @jamesdlin because that wouldn’t work if the contents are not hashable.