# Create range without certain numbers

Tags: python, range

I want to create a range `x` from `0 ... n`, without any of the numbers in the list `y`. How can I do this?

For example:

```
n = 10
y = [3, 7, 8]
x = # Do Something
```

Should give the output:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9]
```

One naive way would be to concatenate several ranges, each spanning a set of numbers which have been intersected by the numbers in `y`. However, I'm not sure of what the simplest syntax to do this is in Python.

Comment: Q: What have you tried?  Q: Have you considered Python [set](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sets) operations?

Answer (score 12):

You can use a list comprehension to filter the range from `0` to `n`: `range(n)` generates a list (or, in Python 3, a generator object) from `0` to `n - 1` (including both ends):

```
x = [i for i in range(n) if i not in y]
```

This filters out all numbers in `y` from the range.

You can also turn it into a generator (which you could only iterate over once but which would be faster for (very) large `n`) by replacing `[` with `(` and `]` with `)`. Further, in Python 2, you can use `xrange` instead of `range` to avoid loading the entire range into memory at once. Also, especially if `y` is a large list, you can turn it into a `set` first to use *O(1)* membership checks instead of *O(n)* on `list` or `tuple` objects. Such a version might look like

```
s = set(y)
x = (i for i in range(n) if i not in s)
```

Comment: It's better to convert `y` into a set to avoid expensive `in` operator for list though.

Comment: Whats that? Did someone say [very relevant post about ```in``` operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368337/tuple-or-list-when-using-in-in-an-if-clause/25368371#25368371)?

Comment: In this example, you can take advantage of the fact that `set(y)` will be built once and reused for each membership test, so the cost of building the set is amortized against the number of elements in the range. The bigger `n` is, the more it makes sense to build the set first. (The linked question is about making a *single* membership test.)

Comment: Oops, fixed that thing (aka rebuilding the set all the time)

Answer (score 8):

hlt's answer is ideal, but I'll quickly suggest another way using `set` operations.

```
n = 10
y = [3, 7, 8]
x = set(range(n)) - set(y)
```

`x` will be a `set` object. If you definitely need `x` to be a `list`, you can just write `x = list(x)`.

Note that the ordering of a set in Python is not guaranteed to be anything in particular. If order is needed, remember to sort.

Comment: While this looks very nice it may (will) not preserve ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the above answers, here is my answer using lambda function:

```
x = filter(lambda x: x not in y,range(n))
```