# Hard coded variables in python function

Tags: python, constants, python-internals

Sometimes, some values/strings are hard-coded in functions. For example in the following function, I define a "constant" comparing string and check against it.

```
def foo(s):
    c_string = "hello"
    if s == c_string:
        return True
    return False
```

Without discussing too much about why it's bad to do this, and how it should be defined in the outer scope, I'm wondering what happens behind the scenes when it **is** defined this way.
Does the string get created each call?
If instead of the string `"hello"` it was the list: `[1,2,3]` (or a list with mutable content if it matters) would the same happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the string is immutable (as would a tuple), it is stored with the bytecode object for the function. It is loaded by a very simple and fast index lookup. This is actually *faster* than a global lookup.

You can see this in a disassembly of the bytecode, using the [`dis.dis()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(s):
...     c_string = "hello"
...     if s == c_string:
...         return True
...     return False
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
              3 STORE_FAST               1 (c_string)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (c_string)
             12 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             15 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22

  4          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             21 RETURN_VALUE        

  5     >>   22 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
             25 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> foo.__code__.co_consts
(None, 'hello')
```

The `LOAD_CONST` opcode loads the string object from the `co_costs` array that is part of the code object for the function; the reference is pushed to the top of the stack. The `STORE_FAST` opcode takes the reference from the top of the stack and stores it in the locals array, again a very simple and fast operation.

For mutable literals (`{..}`, `[..]`) special opcodes build the object, with the contents still treated as constants as much as possible (more complex structures just follow the same building blocks):

```
>>> def bar(): return ['spam', 'eggs']
... 
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('spam')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('eggs')
              6 BUILD_LIST               2
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `BUILD_LIST` call creates the new list object, using two constant string objects.

Interesting fact: If you used a list object for a membership test (`something in ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']` Python knows the list object will never be mutated and will convert it to a tuple for you at compile time (a so-called peephole optimisation). The same applies to a set literal, which is converted to a `frozenset()` object, but only in Python 3.2 and newer. See [Tuple or list when using 'in' in an 'if' clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368337/tuple-or-list-when-using-in-in-an-if-clause)

Note that your sample function is using booleans rather verbosely; you could just have used:

```
def foo(s):
    c_string = "hello"
    return s == c_string
```

for the exact same result, avoiding the `LOAD_GLOBAL` calls in Python 2 (Python 3 made `True` and `False` keywords so the values can also be stored as constants).

Comment: Doesn't the same thing happen with `s == "hello"`?

Comment: You are right about the comment on tuples, I should've asked about list instead. Ill correct the question. The rest of the answer is excellent for now :)

Comment: @ArthurVaiselbuh: I covered lists now too, as well as `{...}` dictionaries and sets.