# Loop while checking if element in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, python-3.x, interpreter

Let's say I have a simple piece of code like this:

```
for i in range(1000):
    if i in [150, 300, 500, 750]:
        print(i)
```

Does the list `[150, 300, 500, 750]` get created every iteration of the loop? Or can I assume that the interpreter (say, CPython 2.7) is smart enough to optimize this away?

Comment: Interesting related question: [Tuple or list when using 'in' in an 'if' clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25368337/953482). Goes into some detail about what CPython does under the hood.

Comment: Unless you specify that you want to know about 1 *specific* interpreter, this is very difficult to answer. Can you rephrase "(say, CPython 2.7)" to specify you want to know about that interpreter exactly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can view the bytecode using [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis). Here's the output for CPython 2.7.11:

```
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              40 (to 43)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                26 (to 42)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             22 LOAD_CONST               6 ((150, 300, 500, 750))
             25 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       13

  4          31 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             34 PRINT_ITEM          
             35 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             36 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
             39 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   42 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   43 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             46 RETURN_VALUE
```

Hence, the list creation is optimized to the loading of a constant tuple (byte 22). The list (which is in reality a tuple in this case) is not created anew on each iteration.