# Immutable objects with same value and type not referencing same object

Tags: python, immutability, python-object

I have been reading the Python Data Model. The following text is taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types):

> Types affect almost all aspects of object behavior. Even the
>   importance of object identity is affected in some sense: for immutable
>   types, operations that compute new values may actually return a
>   reference to any existing object with the same type and value, while
>   for mutable objects this is not allowed. E.g., after `a = 1; b = 1`, `a`
>   and `b` may or may not refer to the same object with the value one,
>   depending on the implementation, but after `c = []; d = []`, `c` and `d` are
>   guaranteed to refer to two different, unique, newly created empty
>   lists. (Note that `c = d = []` assigns the same object to both `c` and `d`.)

So, it mentions that, for immutable types, operations that compute new values may actually return a reference to an existing object with same type and value. So, I wanted to test this. Following is my code:

```
a = (1,2,3)
b = (1,2)
c = (3,)
k = b + c
print(id(a))
>>> 2169349869720    
print(id(k))
>>> 2169342802424
```

Here, I did an operation to compute a new tuple that has same the value and type as `a`. But I got an object referencing to different id. This means I got an object which references different memory than a. Why is this?

Comment: Note "*may* actually return" - it's not guaranteed, it would likely be *less* efficient for Python to look through the existing tuples to find out if one that's the same as the one your operation creates already exists and reuse it than it would to just create a new one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe- So, in what cases python decides to look up and return the same object

Comment: That's implementation dependent, and may vary between compile and run time. In CPython, for example, integers between -5 and 256 (IIRC) are "interned" and reused, so any operation you perform that gives you e.g. 10 returns the same object. Strings are another candidate, strings that represent identifiers are interned.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/15541404/3001761

Comment: Ah, This one. Now, i get that

Comment: So, this would never happen in cases of containers. Always applicable to basic data types

Comment: Tuples (and e.g. frozensets) are immutable containers, so it could happen for them depending on the implementation. But this isn't behaviour to rely on, which is why you e.g. compare strings by equality not identity.

Comment: Thanks. I think i understand this now.

Comment: In some cases CPython even swaps one for the other for efficiency, e.g. the peephole optimisations referenced in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368337/tuple-or-list-when-using-in-in-an-if-clause that convert list -> tuple and set -> frozenset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question based on comments from @jonrsharpe

> Note "may actually return" - it's not guaranteed, it would likely be
> less efficient for Python to look through the existing tuples to find
> out if one that's the same as the one your operation creates already
> exists and reuse it than it would to just create a new one.