# Is there a way to do a condensed conditional statement in python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

Cannot find anything in the documentation about this.

Given the following conditional example:

`if val == 2 or val == 10 or val == 11: ....`

Is there a way to condense this statement without repeating val == ?

Is there something along the lines of :

`if val == 2 or 10 or 11: ....`

Would this be the same time complexity as the original? : `if val in [2,10,11]`

Answer (score 0):

The variant with the `in` operator (`if val in [2, 10, 11]`) is as condensed as you'll get. It has the same time complexity as a series of `==` operators.

Comment: Wouldn't a set be better since membership checking is faster? Assuming the number of checks is sufficiently large.

Comment: Note that if you **really, really** care about performance, you can substitute the list with a tuple. In fact, the compiler does this automatically for small fixed lists, such as the one in your example.

Comment: @xdurch0 Retracting my previous comment - according to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368337/tuple-or-list-when-using-in-in-an-if-clause), it seems like yes, sets are the best option here for Python 3.2+.

Comment: From that link, it sounds like `frozenset` is even better! Learned something today.